# Can I use custom reasons for an HTTP status code to differentiated between errors for a REST API

Tags: http, rest, http-status-codes

I want to differentiate between separate types of "Not Found" errors.  For Example given the following request:

`GET  /author/Adams/works/HHGTTG`

Either the author could be 'not found' or the work could be'not found' and I want to differentiate between the two.

status: 404 - author not found
status: 404 - work not found

According to the spec the reason phrase can be changed. 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

> 6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase
>
> ...The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol...

Is it also acceptable to use two unique phrases for the same status code?

And, is this a sound approach or is there a better convention for indicating more granular errors?

Ultimately I want to have a client library that could throw either an AuthorNotFound or WorkNotFound exception instead of a generic AuthorOrWorkNotFound exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using your "shadowed" not found approach, you could do use 404 with response body:

- use 404 status with text details ('author not found', 'work not found'). To be more language flexible you could use labels (like error.author.notFound)
- use more structured and much easier to parse "subcodes" (e.g. 10 stands for author not found, 11 user not found).

Still I do NOT recommend above mentioned sub-codes, they add a lot of complexity and maintenance effort for uniform HTTP interface. Structure your api-client library differently. Let it call `/author/adams/work/11` first. If it returns 404 then call `/author/adams/` next to find out whether it was the missing author which caused the 404. You then can throw respective NotFound exceptions.

Another alternative is to design the end api-client application differently. It first should call `/author/adams` then if not 404 would proceed `/author/adams/work`. So naturally the application itself is descending the path. But this of course only works if your page flow inside frontend adapts to this call sequence.

Comment: This got me thinking, for my use it's legimate to translate a 404 not found into a

Comment: [previous comment got mangled]
This got me thinking, for my use case it's legitimate to translate a 404 not found into a WorkNotFound even if the real reason is because there's no author.  If I request /author/adams/ and get a 404 that's always translated to a WorkNotFound, and a 404 for /author/adams/work/HHGTTG will always translate the 404 to WorkNotFound.
Client side I can easily determine if WorkNotFound's root cause is AuthorNotFound by looking for the author directly.  Thanks for the helpful tips.

Answer (score 10):

You could have the body of the HTTP response contain a message which you can parse with any additional information.

The HTTP status message on the status code (in the response) can be anything you want and it won't effect any clients.  HTTP clients usually ignore the message text.